# Can you handle Keyboard events (such as pressing left or right arrow) inside a Mac Playground?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, swift-playground

According to SKNode Documentation, if we'd like to handle keyboard events on macOS, we should implement the corresponding methods of NSResponder.

I am currently working on a swift playground, however, I am only able to handle touch events and I'm not sure how I can attach a keydown handler to a SKScene (or any sort of SKNode).

Is it even possible to add such a keydown event inside a Swift Playground?

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, select (right in the beginning when you create your playground) whether you would like to use a macOS or iOS playground. Then, Cocoa is loaded properly and all of its corresponding classes and you can listen to keyboard presses and other form of input like in a normal macOS application.